# Enable subsite on Apache2 with Django

Tags: php, django, apache2

so I have django installed as my main directory

django.conf (in Apache2):

```
Alias /robots.txt /home/django/NAME/static/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /home/django/NAME/static/favicon.ico

Alias /media/ /home/django/NAME/media/
Alias /static/ /home/django/NAME/static/

<Directory /home/django/NAME/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/django/NAME/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/django/NAME/NAME/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonHome /home/django/NAME/venv
WSGIPythonPath /home/django/NAME

<Directory /home/django/NAME/NAME>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Now I want to enable roundcube as mail.NAME.net this is my conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mail.NAME.net                          
        ServerAdmin admin@NAME.net
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/roundcube

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/roundcube_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/roundcube_access.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/html/roundcube>
            Options -Indexes
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mail.keyinator.net
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

**When disabling Django everything works fine. When enabling it I get a 400 Bad Request error on mail.keyinator.net**

So my question is: How can I make my subsite mail.keyinator.net available whilst using django?

Comment: `djanAlias` ??? Typo ?

Comment: yeah, sorry. This was a typo. I corrected it on the server but didn't think of it being here too. But nonetheless the error still exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Changing the file to a virtualhost solved the problem** since I was able to thus add a ServerName

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName NAME.tld
    DocumentRoot /home/django/NAME
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/django/NAME/NAME/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess django display-name=%{GROUP} python-home=/home/django/NAME/venv python-path=/home/django/NAME
    WSGIProcessGroup django

    Alias /robots.txt /home/django/NAME/static/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.ico /home/django/NAME/static/favicon.ico

    Alias /media/ /home/django/NAME/media/
    Alias /static/ /home/django/NAME/static/

    <Directory /home/django/NAME/static>
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/django/NAME/media>
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/django/NAME/NAME>
    <Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
    </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```